# How to make linux 'perf record' work for libc and libstdc++ symbols?

Tags: glibc, profiling, perf

I'm using `perf record -g` on x86-64 Linux to profile a program.  Several symbols in libc or libstdc++ have `0` as a parent: `__GI___strcmp_ssse3` (libc) and `strcmp@plt` (libstdc++) for example.  (I can actually break on these symbols in the debugger and get a backtrace.)

I'd love to know what the major callers of these functions are, and why they are not recorded.  Is this because libc and libstdc++ do not have frame pointers on x86_64? And, more practically, is there some way around this?

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, but this in now possible with `--call-graph dwarf`. From the man page:

```
 -g
       Enables call-graph (stack chain/backtrace) recording.

   --call-graph
       Setup and enable call-graph (stack chain/backtrace) recording, implies -g.

           Allows specifying "fp" (frame pointer) or "dwarf"
           (DWARF's CFI - Call Frame Information) as the method to collect
           the information used to show the call graphs.

           In some systems, where binaries are build with gcc
           --fomit-frame-pointer, using the "fp" method will produce bogus
           call graphs, using "dwarf", if available (perf tools linked to
           the libunwind library) should be used instead.
```

I believe this requires a somewhat recent Linux kernel (>=3.9? I'm not entirely sure). You can check if your distro's perf package is linked with libdw or libunwind with `readelf -d $(which perf) | grep -e libdw -e libunwind`. On Fedora 20, perf is linked with libdw.

Comment: `perf record --call-graph dwarf` solves this problem for me. unfortunately, it seems that perf has problems showing caller-based (i.e. "inverted") call-graphs when using dwarf information. That is why I started using FlameGraph for visualisation.

Comment: note that using dwarf unwinding causes very significant overhead during profiling

Answer (score -3):

`perf` is a kernel tool which shows elapsed time for system calls.
You are looking for GNU gprof. "gprof - display call graph profile data".
To use gprof you need to compile your sources with the `-pg` switch.

Beside of this there are a lot of sophisticated profiling tools like `eclipse-cdt-profiling-framework`.